# How to process expanded macros from within procedural macros?

Tags: plugins, macros, rust

For [overflower](https://github.com/llogiq/overflower), I'm trying to replace all arithmetic operations (binary `+`, `-`, `*`, `/`, `%`, `<<`, `>>` and unary `-`) with corresponding trait method calls. However, I'm hitting a wall with macros. Ideally, I'd work on the already expanded macro, but this does not appear to work.

I've followed the suggestion in `syntax::fold::Folder::fold_mac(..)` and called `noop_fold_mac(mac, self)`, but that does not appear to do anything to stuff inside a macro, like `assert_eq!(2, 1 + 1)`. I don't care about the code pre-expansion, so how do I have my macro work on the expanded code?

I could probably work on the `TokenTrees` directly, but that's cumbersome.

I'm using `rustc 1.11.0-nightly (915b003e3 2016-06-02)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`expand_expr`](http://manishearth.github.io/rust-internals-docs/syntax/ext/expand/fn.expand_expr.html) function to do a full expansion (if let, macros, etc...). You need a [`MacroExpander`](http://manishearth.github.io/rust-internals-docs/syntax/ext/expand/struct.MacroExpander.html), which you can get by passing a mutable reference to the [`ExtCtxt`](http://manishearth.github.io/rust-internals-docs/syntax/ext/base/struct.ExtCtxt.html) to the [`MacroExpander::new`](http://manishearth.github.io/rust-internals-docs/syntax/ext/expand/struct.MacroExpander.html#method.new) method or call the `ExtCtxt`'s `expander()` method.

The actual code is:

```
fn fold_expr(&mut self, expr: P<Expr>) -> P<Expr> {
    ..
    if let ExprKind::Mac(_) = expr.node {
        let expanded = expand_expr(expr.unwrap(), &mut self.cx.expander());
        return self.fold_expr(expanded);
    }
    ..
}
```

Edit: For completeness, one should also expand Items with ItemKind::Mac; there's an `syntax::ext::expand::expand_item(..)` method working similarly to `expand_expr(..)`.

Comment: This is no longer possible with the current `proc_macro` API.